# Is “just finished to” right?

Tags: verbs, verb-forms

I want to know if is right to say the following sentence:

> I just finished to read the book.

If it’s not right, or another way is better, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four (or five) types of clauses which may act as complements to English verbs, distinguished by the complementizer (if any) which introduces the clause and the form of the verb which 'heads' the clause. (Sometimes the complementizer may be omitted; where that is the case I have put it in parentheses.):

- (*that*) ... finite verb (past- or present-form) - "I see ***that*** he **is running** away*.
- *wh- form* ... finite verb - "I see ***where*** he **is running**."
- *∅* (no complementizer) ...  gerund (*-ing* form) "I see *him **running** away*."
- *∅* ... (*to* +) infinitive "I see *him **run** away*." "I want *him **to run** away.*
- *for* ... *to* + infinitive - "I hate ***for*** him **to run** away." (*Some grammarians treat this is as a full construction and the* ∅ ... (to +) infinitive *type as a reduced version*.)

Each English verb 'selects' some of these as acceptable and rejects others. There is no pattern by which you can predict which types will be acceptable; you have to learn each verb's complements one-by-one.

*Finish* takes only gerund and *wh-* clauses as complements:

> I just finished ***reading*** the book. 
>   I just finished ***what*** I **started** yesterday.

Comment: Can you give examples of the other three possibilities? I think that would be helpful.

Comment: @J.R. There you go, with the list fixed, too.

Comment: It's possibly worth adding that conversely, it's perfectly acceptable to say "I just *started* to read the book." Of course, you can also say "I just started reading the book."

Comment: You wrote "Sometimes the complementizer **may** be omitted".  I think it could help to point out that sometimes the complementizer **must** be omitted.

Comment: @snailboat You're right, and I'll fix that. Is that the case with any complementizer other than *for*? And should *for ... to* be distinguished as a fifth construction, distinct from *∅ ... (to)*? I'm of two minds.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I didn't explain with precision. 
My questions is about the "finished to read" or "finished reading", don't about the "just".

Thanks a lot for all answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct way:  "I just finished reading the book."

Comment: You're correct, although it may be worth adding that we could strike the word _reading_, and the sentence would still mean the same thing and be grammatically correct: "I just finished the book."

Comment: Good point. Your way is more common anyway.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why it's correct or why the version in the question is incorrect, so it's not very helpful.

Comment: @J.R. But it might not mean the same thing: it might mean "I just finished *writing* the book" - or editing or burning it.

Comment: @Stoney - True, you'd need context to determine the meaning of the word "finished" in that sentence. But it could be done, as in: "Have you read _A Study in Scarlet_?" Answer: "Yes, I just finished it."

Comment: I've learned 3 languages without ever learning the grammatical jargon that only serves to confuse. 'Gerund', 'helping verb', 'complementizer', it's better to just listen and learn the way people say things rather than get bogged down in the grammatical jargon that doesn't help.